# Gmail multi conditional filter on email order

Tags: gmail-filters

I monitor application builds and could get the following emails with the subject:

1. First Email: "Build Failed - {My Application}"
2. Second Email: "Build back to normal - {My Application}"

The time between the emails can be delayed.

The filter rule I want to create is once second email is delivered, mark that one plus the "Build Failed" for that matching application "My Application" to "Read".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid no, it's not possible. Gmail filters can only perform actions on the message that triggered the filter. There is not a way with Gmail filters to act on a different message than the one the filters are currently "acting on".